# Debugging with Xdebug for cli php on vagrant machine

Tags: php, vagrant, xdebug, remote-debugging

I use a Centos vagrant machine on which the project resides. I have enabled synced folder to the project root folder so that I can edit directly on the machine from Windows. I use VSCode or NetBeans as editor.

Now how do I debug in this situation? The code is in PHP. Local machine does not have any environments like php/apache set up. Everything is on the vagrant machine. The php script is run on vagrant while providing parameters through command line, eg -

```
/path/index.php folderName scriptname function_name param1 param2 param3
```

I already installed xdebug on vagrant. Xdebug options in `php.ini`

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Now how do i debug php scripts and see step by step what changes in VSCode or NetBeans? The php codes are cli. Tried several guides, no luck. The php files have no webpage view.

Just found that `$ netstat -aon | grep 9000` returns nothing.

Comment: Hi. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search finds plenty of howtos and articles:

- https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/
- https://tighten.co/blog/configure-vscode-to-debug-phpunit-tests-with-xdebug
- https://medium.com/@jaythedeveloper/ultimate-guide-debug-php-iis-in-visual-studio-code-using-xdebug-14fced013f22
- https://jonathansblog.co.uk/remote-debugging-php-in-visual-studio-code-with-xdebug
- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-debug-with-xdebug/

Comment: Do not these require a local php installed?
Added `xdebug.remote_enable=1` on `php.ini`.
`netstat -aon | grep 9000` returns nothing on vagrant machine.

Comment: It does not matter where the PHP is installed - XDebug will try to connect to port 9000 (by default) on the same IP where the page request is coming from. So if XDebug runs inside Vagrant but you are browsing from your host machine - then XDebug will try to connect to your host machine on port 9000. Make sure there is no firewall interfering. And if these tutorials do not match 100% your situation - I am sure there are others on Google.